# Good source for launch videos

Tags: launch

Does anyone know a good source for watching/downloading launch videos (saved webcasts for example of SpaceX and NASA ). Launch videos are extremely informative especially as they are curated for the general public.

Comment: SpaceX webcast are streamed over Youtube and so are then accessible there for replays - for example [CRS-8 hosted webcast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pUAydjne5M) and in the sidebar I could see the its NASA post-launch conference and JCSAT-14 webcast.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the ultimate Shuttle launch video is [Ascent](https://sites.google.com/site/ascentcommemoratingshuttle/home): about an hour of footage from dozens of high-speed cameras.

ESA has a [video section](http://www.esa.int/spaceinvideos/content/search?SearchText=launch&SearchButton=Go) on their website that contains lots of launch webcasts.

SpaceX have a [Youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/spacexchannel) and a [video section](http://www.spacex.com/media/all/video) on their website.

Answer (score 0):

The Internet Archive has a lot of older public domain NASA material.

For example: footage from the [Apollo 16mm launch cameras](https://archive.org/details/APOLLO16MMLAUNCHVIEWS) for various launches, all rolled into one very long slow-motion movie. These show detail of disconnection of the various support umbilicals during the launch sequence. (No sound.)